# How to declare a structured array type in numpy similar to this C struct?

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following c-struct:

```
typedef struct
        {
            int blah[10];
        } mine;
```

How can I declare a structured numpy array dtype for this?

I tried:

```
mine_dtype = [
            ('blah', [np.int32])
        ]
```

But that doesn't work.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean, 'it doesn't work'?  Error the definition, or in how you use it?

Comment: Yeah I mean it’s invalid dtype.

Comment: What do you mean by _"declare a structured numpy array"_? There is no way to _declare_ types in Python. You just create a numpy array instead. For example `np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=np.int32)`

Comment: Can you expand on the use case you have in mind? It's quite unclear what you actually want to do.

Comment: Please always share the entire error message. I agree with @Lagerbaer, I think it would be good to have some more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [267]: mine_dtype = [ 
     ...:             ('blah', [np.int32]) 
     ...:         ]                                                                              
In [268]: np.dtype(mine_dtype)                                                                   
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-268-6f0bb6a0df45> in <module>
----> 1 np.dtype(mine_dtype)

TypeError: data type not understood
In [269]: mine_dtype = [ 
     ...:             ('blah', np.int32) 
     ...:         ]                                                                              
In [270]: np.dtype(mine_dtype)                                                                   
Out[270]: dtype([('blah', '<i4')])
In [271]: np.ones(3, dtype=mine_dtype)                                                           
Out[271]: array([(1,), (1,), (1,)], dtype=[('blah', '<i4')])
In [272]: _['blah']                                                                              
Out[272]: array([1, 1, 1], dtype=int32)
```

expanding the dtype to specify 10 elements per field:

```
In [282]: mine_dtype = [ 
     ...:             ('blah', np.int32, 10) 
     ...:         ]                                                                              
In [283]: arr = np.zeros(3,mine_dtype)                                                           
In [284]: arr                                                                                    
Out[284]: 
array([([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],),
       ([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],),
       ([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],)], dtype=[('blah', '<i4', (10,))])
In [285]: arr['blah'][:]=np.arange(10)                                                           
In [286]: arr                                                                                    
Out[286]: 
array([([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],),
       ([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],),
       ([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],)], dtype=[('blah', '<i4', (10,))])
```